# get the length of video selected or Recorded through iPhone Camera xcode

Tags: iphone, video, xcode4, uiimagepickercontroller, duration

I am working on Fetching a video from Video Library or Recording  a new video.Once selected in imagepicker method didfinishpickingmediawithinfo: i need to find th duration of Video that is selected from my Video album also the  on i recorded from Camera.
I have used AVAsset  to fetch the duration in CMTime
also i referred to MPMoviePlayer to fetch the duration of video but they don't provide me such property.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:recordedTmpFile];

CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) just add the AVFoundation framwork in your app

2)  then  import the header file to your controller

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

3) then add the above code written by victor.

```
NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:recordedTmpFile];

CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController has a property duration.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval duration
```

Please note that this property is **read-only**.

As per documentation

If the duration of the movie is not known, the value in this property is 0.0. If the duration is subsequently determined, this property is updated and a MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification notification is posted.

But why you are preferring MPMoviewPlayerController? AVFoundation is much faster for this type of operation. And you don't need to wait for any notification like in MPMoviewPlayerController.

if you would like to go through AVAsset. Here is a exact answer : [MPMoviePlayerController - Duration always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982893/mpmovieplayercontroller-duration-always-0)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers to this question using AVPlayerItem didn't work for me, but this did using AVURLAsset:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *videoURL=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

    NSTimeInterval durationInSeconds = 0.0;
    if (asset)
        durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
}
```